# You have an error in my request but which?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

The request of my function has a problem:

```
function rdvDelete($rdv)
{
    $pdo = connexion();
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM visitors,rdvs WHERE rdvs.idRdv = :rdv AND visitors.idVisitor = rdvs.idVisitor"); <-- line 34
    $sql->execute(['rdv' => $rdv]);
}
```

$rdv = 3 !!!

And this display this error

> [error] 639#639: *9791 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal
> error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near 'WHERE rdvs.idRdv = ? AND visitors.idVisitor =
> rdvs.idVisitor' at line 1 in
> /var/www/MY-WEBSITE/model/m_manage-rdvs.php:34

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your prepared statement has an error. You need to specify both parameters in the statement before executing with the actual values of the parameters. Do this

```
function rdvDelete($rdv)
{

    $pdo = connexion();
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM visitors,rdvs WHERE rdvs.idRdv = :rdv AND visitors.idVisitor = :rdvs); <-- line 34
    $sql->execute(['rdv' => $rdv, 'rdvs' = $rdvs]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support explicit or implicit joins in `DELETE` statements. You are attempting the implicit join with comma separated tables in `FROM` clause and join condition in `WHERE`. For correlated delete statements, consider using `IN` or `EXISTS` operators on a subquery:

```sql
DELETE FROM visitors
WHERE idVisitor IN (
    SELECT rdvs.idVisitor
    FROM rdvs
    WHERE rdvs.idRdv = :rdv
)
```

```sql
DELETE FROM visitors
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM rdvs
    WHERE rdvs.idVisitor = visitors.idVisitor
      AND rdvs.idRdv = :rdv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this query :

```
DELETE visitors, rdvs FROM visitors INNER JOIN rdvs ON visitors.idVisitor = rdvs.idVisitor WHERE rdvs.idRdv = :rdv
```